# Avoid using let and mutating values with react componet with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Question. Based on recent informationthat i got, I was sugested that:

> avoid using let and mutating values in react components because variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render.

So let say we have such simple example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./Timer.scss";

interface ITimerProps {
  setValid: (valid: boolean) => void;
}

export const Timer = ({ setValid }: ITimerProps) => {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const tokenTTL = 1;
  const endTime = new Date();
  let min = tokenTTL;
  let sec = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + tokenTTL);

      sec--;
      if (sec === -1) {
        sec = 59;
        min--;
      }

      setMinutes(min);
      setSeconds(sec);

      if (min === 0 && sec === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setValid(false);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <p className="Timer">
        <span className="minutes">{minutes}</span>
        <span className="divider">:</span>
        <span className="seconds">{seconds}</span>
      </p>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here I am using let for seconds and minutes. And based on that I am just rendering a simple timer and I do have to use let just to mutate my values

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the sort of use case they mean, as you're only calling `useEffect()` once and everything else is done in a single `setInterval()`.

Having said that, you can make your code more readable (and conforming to the advice) by moving the mutable variables inside `useEffect()`.

*It's also a good idea to provide React with a means to clear your interval when the component is unmounted by [returning a cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).*